# autocomplete gets in the way on method signature

Tags: autocomplete, appcode

errr ... dumb question but i could not find the appropriate settings for this.

When editing code, trying to add a new method in class , as shown below :

[image: snapshot of edit session]

Line 355 shows my intended input.  When typing it (as shown on line 360), Appcode suggests a bunch of totally irrelevant choices. Can I configure to stop that? I would normally type `text[space]` and get the annoying `textInputContextIdentifier` instead of my intent.

Comment: @downvoter  : care to explain ? maybe I can improve the question to suit your personal goodness criteria for questions on SO.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me. Despite using AppCode often, I hadn't noticed this -- I think because I rarely type method signatures in the implementation file. Note that this doesn't happen in header files, nor the 'add method' intention dialogue, nor in IntelliJ (in java source). I'd call this a code completion bug. Maybe you should report it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in completion, track [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14279) for information about the progress on it.

The possible workaround is do not spent your time on first defining the method signature - try using the method which does not exists in the same way as it's already created, have the red code, press Alt+Enter and select "Create method". Press Enter and have the method stub created in .m file. [image: Create from usage] After it, move cursor to the method signature, press Alt+Enter and have the declaration automatically created in .h file.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to submit bug report. I dont anymore, since i feel Jetbrains is dragging their feet an anything that is not a show-stopper. The whole process is a cold waste of my time. I sometimes post here in case some smart colleagues found a work-around.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Tbh, I deal with our users everyday and everywhere. And first I want to thank you for all your reports in our tracker, but second, let's look on them https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC?q=created%20by:YvesLeBorg. The most is processed and either resolved as a duplicate or fixed in case it was possible to reproduce it. Yes, it's impossible to fix everything, and we are sometimes limited with resources, but I'm honestly thinking, that it's a good coverage in case of such big product as AppCode.

Comment: As i said , i dont bother anymore. There are many irritants (downright bugs) that date 5-6 years on which there are no actions. AppCode itself is slowly drifting towards a passable IDE. When code editing is hardly better than xcode, but i have to switch all the time , guess what percentage of my i spend with AppCode at this point. I only go there for one feature these days : some intense refactoring or re-purposing session.